# CSS Selectors - If child class = ? then select the parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Say I have the following CSS:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3">
            <ul class="div4">
                <li class="div5">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to target, **if li.div5 then target .div1**  so like change the background of .div1 if li.div5 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('li.div5').length) {
    $(this).parents('.div1')......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS - No, I'm afraid there is no parent selector.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't with css only . there's not such selector working as an *ancestor* selector

Answer (score 0):

CSS *cascades*, so it only allows selection of children. There are no ascension selectors unless you implement something like `jQuery` and do it through javascript.