# How to select DOM parent from child in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

is it possible to effect a parent node based on a child node's :hover state? ie.

```
nav ul li a:hover {
  /* something here to effect the li or the ul or the nav elements */
}
```

not that bothered about compatibility, I am looking to be using latest firefox/chrome and ie9/10 only based on the target audience of the app. So CSS3 and browser specific CSS is fine, though I would like to avoid jQuery (and javascript in general) if possible.

Comment: No, with CSS this is ([so far/currently](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview)) impossible (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115487/css-selectors-if-child-class-then-select-the-parent (among many, *many* others). If it must be done, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible *right now*, as you can only style downstream siblings or descendants while hovering other another element (as of [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/))

However, when [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/) becomes stable and UA's start implementing it, you can eventually use the parent combinator - e.g.

```
<h2>Hello<span>World</span></h2>
```

---

```
h2! > span:hover {
background: azure; /*the h2 background changes while hovering over the span */
}
```

Comment: I was wondering where did this answer go :)

Comment: I notice you're linking to the latest (2nd May) draft - that revision of the draft includes a note about fast/complete profiles, which basically excludes `!` from the fast profile, in turn excluding it from being used in CSS. Also see my latest comment on the accepted answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use javascript `onmousehover` event instead.
Something like,

```
<script>
function onhoverstylechange()
{
    document.getElementById("id").style.color='red';
}
</script>
<div id="id">
    <a href="#" onmouseover="onhoverstylechange()">Change</a>
</div>
```

and just apply any css or css file in the javascript function.

Comment: Please don't hard-code the `id` with this, just use (if you *must* use in-line JavaScript) `onmouseover="onHoverStyleChange(this, 'color','#f00')"` and (in the function) `elem.parentNode.style[property] = value;`. Your current approach requires a separate function for every element to whose parent should change `onmouseover`, *and* for ever property to be changed therein.